# Wine not running games despite having Directx9. HELP!

Tags: wine, games

[I am getting this error when i try to run Project IGI 1 with wine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JBQH.png)

It asks me to install directx 7.0 or higher but I already have directx9
[When I tried to install directx9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyrfJ.png)
I am a complete newbie to both laptops and ubuntu OS. Help me in running this game.
PS I am on 16.04 LTS and using wine 2.18

Comment: is Project IGI 1 a 64-bit program? I would create a 32-bit prefex, Install directx9 and the game in that prefix. https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=27296

Comment: @ravery how do I run the game via 32 bit after switching from 64??

Comment: and how to exit the game after playing?

Comment: did you create a 32-bit prefix?  q4wine is a good GUI for managing prefixes `sudo apt-get install q4wine`